# How to display field values without displaying objectID?

Tags: mongodb

I want to display the last name field in my database but it should not have the object ID. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are using find then: `find({<whatever you need here>},{_id: 0})

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`db.salesman.find({},{"FirstName":1,"_id":0})`